# CUDA: determining # of thread blocks within a grid

Tags: cuda

I am looking at one of the simple sample CUDA programs and had a question about how it determined the # of blocks in the grid.  The relevant part of the code is:

```
// Launch the Vector Add CUDA Kernel
int threadsPerBlock = 256;
int blocksPerGrid =(numElements + threadsPerBlock - 1) / threadsPerBlock;
printf("CUDA kernel launch with %d blocks of %d threads\n", blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock);
vectorAdd<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>(d_A, d_B, d_C, numElements);
```

Why is blocksPerGrid equal to

```
(numElements + threadsPerBlock - 1) / threadsPerBlock
```

and not just

```
numElements / threadsPerBlock
```

?

Comment: Ask yourself what happens if `numElement < threadsPerBlock` or `numElements` isn't a round multiple of `threadsPerBlock` in both cases

Answer (score 3):

This gives integer division:

```
numElements / threadsPerBlock
```

If `numElements` is not evenly divisible by `threadsPerBlock`, then this won't give the correct result - we need an extra threadblock to cover the "extra" threads needed.

This arithmetic:

```
(numElements + threadsPerBlock - 1) / threadsPerBlock
```

gives us an extra threadblock, as needed.